# How to divide second column by first column in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, triangle

```
     DP 1       DP 2        DP 3       DP 4        DP 5         DP 6        DP 7        DP 8       DP 9        DP 10
 3,57,848    11,24,788   17,35,330   22,18,270   27,45,596   33,19,994   34,66,336   36,06,286   38,33,515   39,01,463 
 3,52,118    12,36,139   21,70,033   33,53,322   37,99,067   41,20,063   46,47,867   49,14,039   53,39,085  
 2,90,507    12,92,306   22,18,525   32,35,179   39,85,995   41,32,918   46,28,910   49,09,315      
 3,10,608    14,18,858   21,95,047   37,57,447   40,29,929   43,81,982   45,88,268          
 4,43,160    11,36,350   21,28,333   28,97,821   34,02,672   38,73,311              
 3,96,132    13,33,217   21,80,715   29,85,752   36,91,712                  
 4,40,832    12,88,463   24,19,861   34,83,130                      
 3,59,480    14,21,128   28,64,498                          
 3,76,686    13,63,294                              
 3,44,014
```

I've this triangle dataframe(df1) , i wanted to calculate new dataframe(df2) that contains the result:second_column(df2)/first_column(df2) and third_column(df2)/second_column(df2) and so on..

i tried like this(i know its wrong).

```
for colname, col in df1.iteritems():
            df1[colname7] = df1['second_column']/df1['first_column']
```

and i wanted df2 like this:

```
  DP 1   DP 2    DP 3    DP 4    DP 5    DP 6    DP 7    DP 8    DP 9   DP 10
 3.14    1.54    1.28    1.24    1.21    1.04    1.04    1.06    1.02    -   
 3.51    1.76    1.55    1.13    1.08    1.13    1.06    1.09    -      
 4.45    1.72    1.46    1.23    1.04    1.12    1.06    -          
 4.57    1.55    1.71    1.07    1.09    1.05    -              
 2.56    1.87    1.36    1.17    1.14    -                  
 3.37    1.64    1.37    1.24    -                      
 2.92    1.88    1.44    -                          
 3.95    2.02    -                              
 3.62    -
```

Thank You for your time..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to remove the commas and convert the dataframe to float type:

```
df2 = df1.replace(',', '', regex = True).astype(float)
```

Then you can divide directly by shifting the columns once:

```
df2 = df2.shift(-1, axis = 1).div(df2)
```

**Output**

```
df2
       DP 1      DP 2      DP 3      DP 4      DP 5      DP 6      DP 7      DP 8      DP 9  DP 10
0  3.143200  1.542806  1.278299  1.237719  1.209207  1.044079  1.040374  1.063009  1.017725    NaN
1  3.510582  1.755493  1.545286  1.132926  1.084493  1.128106  1.057268  1.086496       NaN    NaN
2  4.448450  1.716718  1.458257  1.232079  1.036860  1.120010  1.060577       NaN       NaN    NaN
3  4.568002  1.547052  1.711784  1.072518  1.087360  1.047076       NaN       NaN       NaN    NaN
4  2.564198  1.872956  1.361545  1.174217  1.138315       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN    NaN
5  3.365588  1.635679  1.369162  1.236443       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN    NaN
6  2.922798  1.878099  1.439393       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN    NaN
7  3.953288  2.015651       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN    NaN
8  3.619179       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN    NaN
9       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN    NaN
```

---

Optionally you can round with:

```
df2 = df2.round(2)
```

Comment: Love this answer. Nice use of shift

Comment: @MichaelScofield You're welcome, I'm happy to help :)

Comment: @PabloC i've another problem in dataframe: i've the formula `=SUMPRODUCT(E17:E26,B3:B12)/SUM(OFFSET(B3,0,0,10-COLUMNS($B$3:B3))) ` in excel. How can i implement in python data frame .

Comment: @MichaelScofield mmh I don't know excel but anyway, I recommend you to post a new question about that with more details